# Why does LDFLAGS put my libraries before object files generating undefined references?

Tags: c, makefile, ld, ldflags

Here's what happens.

```
$ LDFLAGS=-ltestu01 make exemplo
cc   -ltestu01  exemplo.c   -o exemplo
/home/melba/tmp/ccO2KkjG.o: In function `main':
exemplo.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `unif01_CreateExternGenBits'
exemplo.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `bbattery_SmallCrush'
exemplo.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `unif01_DeleteExternGenBits'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'exemplo' failed
make: *** [exemplo] Error 1
%
```

I expected the command to be `cc exemplo.c -o exemplo -ltestu01`.  How can I make sure the hints to the linker go to the end of the command line?

Comment: Can you post your `$(CC)` (or whatever it is) line from your Makefile?

Comment: Because `LDFLAGS` is not intended for specifying objects (including libraries) to include in the link.

Comment: @FiddlingBits No Makefile exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`make -p` prints the default recipes.

Your recipe should be:

```
%: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

From this, it should be obvious you should be setting `LDLIBS`, not `LDFLAGS`.

```
make exemplo LDLIBS=-ltestu01 -B
```

runs

```
cc     examplo.c  -ltestu01 -o exemplo
```

as expected. It seems the intention is that `LDFLAGS` is for things like `-Wl,--something`.